# ionic 3: click button smooth to top (When the scroll is not complete)

Tags: cordova, ionic3

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/

In this link write about scrolltotop.  This syntax must completed the scroll to work. But I want to scrolling click the button to smooth to top (not use hashtag). Who knows about it? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...}) 
export class MyPage{
   @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

   scrollToTop() {
   this.content.scrollTo(0, 0, durationInMs)
  }
}
```